# Index out of bound exception with selected row in table

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having index out of bound exception when selecting a row from table view. Here is how I fetch the data from database:

```
 public List<Category> populateCategoryTable() {
    List ll = new LinkedList();

    try {
        db.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM sm_category";
        ResultSet rs = null;
        // Call readRequest to get the result
        rs = db.readRequest(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String ID = rs.getString("categoryID");
            String name = rs.getString("categoryName");
            String desc = rs.getString("categoryDescription");
            Category row = new Category();
            row.setid(ID);
            row.setname(name);
            row.setdesc(desc);
            ll.add(row);
        }
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error SQL!!!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return ll;
}
```

And this is how I set up my table view:

```
public void setUpCategoryTable() {
    TableColumn IDCol = new TableColumn("ID");
    IDCol.setVisible(false);
    IDCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Category, String>("ID"));

    TableColumn nameCol = new TableColumn("Name");
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Category, String>("name"));

    TableColumn descCol = new TableColumn("Description");
    descCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Category, String>("desc"));

    viewCategory.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
    viewCategory.setEditable(false);
    viewCategory.getColumns().addAll(IDCol, nameCol, descCol);
    viewCategory.getItems().setAll(populateCategoryTable());
```

//Error occurs after adding these codes to get selected row from table

```
    viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE); // just in case you didnt already set the selection model to multiple selection.
    viewCategory.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().addListener(new ListChangeListener<TablePosition>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends TablePosition> change) {
            TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = viewCategory.getSelectionModel();
            ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
            TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
            int row = tablePosition.getRow(); // yields the row that the currently selected cell is in
            System.out.println(row);
        }
    });
```

//Error ends

public class Category {

```
    private SimpleStringProperty ID;
    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleStringProperty desc;

    public void setid(String value) {
        IDProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getid() {
        return IDProperty().get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty IDProperty() {
        if (ID == null) {
            ID = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "ID");
        }
        return ID;
    }

    public void setname(String value) {
        nameProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getname() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        if (name == null) {
            name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        }
        return name;
    }

    public void setdesc(String value) {
        descProperty().set(value);
    }

    public String getdesc() {
        return descProperty().get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty descProperty() {
        if (desc == null) {
            desc = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "desc");
        }
        return desc;
    }
}
```

However, I got index out of bound exception after I added the junk of selected row code. The error message is:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:208)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$6.get(TableView.java:1757)
at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel$6.get(TableView.java:1755)
at shopManagement.boundary.RetrieveProductUI$1.onChanged(RetrieveProductUI.java:101)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:48)
```

Does anybody know why is there index out of bound exception? There is no red line in my code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your table structure. What are the names of the columns?

Comment: Provide full stacktrace having details of your classes so that we can see the exact point of error

Comment: I have no problem with retrieving data from database and display it in table. The error only occurs when I select the row in table. I will comment out the part. See my updates

Comment: check size of selectedCells in onchange function,i think whenever you are selecting a row and calling onchange, that time there is no selectedCell in the list.

Comment: Ya it shows me [] in console. So how should I fix it?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar I think it's because I retrieving data from database using a linked list then I never store it into the ObservableList. But do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ObservableList by FXCollections, if you just use table.getItems() it will be created automatically, so usage table.getItems().setAll(...) is fine, you can easy verify that with debugger.

Following code should help:

```
while(change.next(){
    if(change.wasAdded()){
        TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = viewCategory.getSelectionModel();
        ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
        TablePosition tablePosition = (TablePosition) selectedCells.get(0);
        int row = tablePosition.getRow(); // yields the row that the currently selected cell is in
        System.out.println(row);
    }
}
```

Also you can change this code:

```
TableView.TableViewSelectionModel selectionModel = viewCategory.getSelectionModel();
ObservableList selectedCells = selectionModel.getSelectedCells();
```

With:

```
ObservableList selectedCells = change.getList();
```

But, if you wants just sout last selected row, you can use:

UPD:

```
    //viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    //viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
    viewCategory.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number number1) {
                    if ((Integer) number1 >= 0) {
                        Category cat = (Category) table.getItems().get(number1);
                        String id = cat.getid();
                        \\here you can fetch DB for aditional info and pass it somewhere
                    } 
                }
            });
```

Comment: You mean adding the if statement in the changeListener? Also where to get the List? Because I am retrieving data dynamically. I do not have manual observable list to set the data. if following your code, I get IllegalStateException

Comment: @Carol, event target list will be taken, on change.getList() calling. ObservableList is created by TableView, but i am not sure when, possibly, on instance creation, or lazy on first call of getItems().

Comment: But I got IllegalStateException. Do you know why?

Comment: But aren't it supposed to just get the first column value of selected row? Do we need to add new element?

Comment: Try to add additional code: while (change.next()) {\\code from post} Sorry, forgot about initial state.

Comment: We can try to get chagnes by change.getAddedSubList() it should contain selected part.

Comment: It's fixed. But your code is according to the row number in table view? it's not following the first column value? As in like the getValueAt() method in javaSwing

Comment: You can use indexOf() for that purpose, search AddedSubList indexes at table.getItems(), but i guess this method is not the fastest one. Better approach is use getFrom() and getTo() methods, if was multiple selection with Shift key, thet will determine interval of selection, otherwise they will has same values witch are equal index of selected item at main list.

Comment: so getValueAt() in javaSwing = indexOf() in javaFX? Can you please give me some example?

Comment: i mean change.getFrom() and change.getTo()

Comment: Oh okay. But is there any other way to amend my codes so that it takes the first column value which is ID in database of selected row?

Comment: Are you sure you need multiple selection? If you do, use getAddedSubList() this list already contains selected Category instances, use following code if TableView is generifyed: for(Category cat : getAddedSubList){ String id = cat.getid(); \\use your id }

Comment: No no it's not multiple selection. It's like my table column are ID, name and description. So I get the first column which is ID of selected row, but the ID is following the data in database which is jumbled up so you can not simply count the row index, then I pass the ID around.

Comment: Heh, than set viewCategory.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE); and use code from last part of my post

Comment: No no it's not about the number of selection. What I mean is, from your code, it just simply count the number of row start from 0 right? It's not getting the value of first column of selected row. As what I've said, my first column is ID which is from database, and the numbering in database start with 1. So there's a crash

Comment: Yes you are rigth it is simple numbers of row starting with 0, but you can add 1, and use them as ids if you wish. But i think better approach is use ID taken from a value, because if you will delete some records from a head of the table problems may occurs.

Comment: Ya but how to use ID taken from a value as you've said?

Comment: Please see UPD at post, i guess thats all you need.

Comment: what is UPD? and where is it